# I have a volume mounted into a Kubernetes pod, the volume has 644 permissions, but the container user is non-root, can I force mount as 777?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, volume

I'm running this on a Openstack Magnum kubernetes cluster and am trying to figure out why this problem occurs.. Can I force a mount as 777 ?

To illustrate:

```
bash-5.1$ whoami
postgres
bash-5.1$ cd /var/pv/
bash-5.1$ ls -slah
total 28K    
     4 drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root        4.0K Mar 25 22:22 .
     0 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          27 Mar 25 22:22 ..
    16 drwx------    2 root     root       16.0K Mar 25 22:22 lost+found
     4 drwxr-x---    2 root     root        4.0K Mar 25 22:22 raftsnapshot
     4 drwx------    2 root     root        4.0K Mar 25 22:22 raftwal
bash-5.1$
```

This folder is mounted into /var/pv, and is meant to store postgres data. I need the postgres user to make files in this directory.

Comment: Could you please share your yaml configs by editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems [this](https://faun.pub/digitalocean-kubernetes-and-volume-permissions-820f46598965) is what you need